# C# in Unity with Visual Studio - Debugger skips lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

I am working with C# in Unity with visual studio. If I use a data structure like this:

```
bool[,] arr = new bool[rows, cols];
```

This works fine. I then try to assign to this array like this:

```
arr[row, col] = true;
```

The problem is when the debugger gets to this line, it immediately steps out of the function. I tried wrapping it in a `try/catch` block, and there is no exception being thrown. The code runs fine, the debugger just refuses to debug past an assignment to a multidimensional array. I tried using a jagged array instead, and the debugger will then run normally (it works normally on a list of lists too). However there are cases where I am forced to use multidimensional arrays. Does anybody know what is going on, and how to fix this error?

EDIT: Here is a dummy, self-contained class that will cause the problem to occur:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrayTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool[,] arr;
    private int numRows = 8;
    private int numCols = 11;
    bool truthVal = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
       arr = new bool[numRows, numCols];
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        AssignArr();
    }

    public void AssignArr()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j)
            {
                arr[i, j] = truthVal;
            }
        }

        truthVal = !truthVal;
    }
}
```

All this does is iterate over the array and change all of its truth values. The debugger will run through the loop in `AssignArr()` once before stepping out.

Comment: Can you post your whole method (or at least a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? It's hard to tell what your problem is without seeing more context. It would also help if I could run code that had the alleged error.

Comment: the whole method will be large. In fact in the initial case I ran into this problem, the structure was a member variable, and the assignments occurred in multiple different methods. I will try to post a verifiable example though, give me a second to create.

Comment: Also, one thing I would check if your build is in release mode. Some variables get optimized away by the compiler which makes them unavailable to the debugger. If this is happening with a Debug build, it is likely something else.

Comment: i attached an example class that cause the problem. The build is in debug mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you your class doesn't inherit `MonoBehaviour` (i.e. your class definition would be just `public class ArrayTest`), does your issue still occur? I ran your code without it, and saw no issues.

Comment: I would report a bug to unity using the built in bug reporter with the simple example that still reliably reproduces the problem. The code should work.

Comment: @Nik Were you running it in unity or as a C# standalone? It probably relates to the interaction between visual studio and Unity. 
see [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1431276/multidimensional-array-debugging-error.html)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain done.